# The dummy variable trap

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear, categorical-encoding

I find a lot of resources online which explains the dummy variable trap and that you should remove 1 category of your dummy variable before fitting it into a multilinear model to avoid multicollinearity.
While I understand **what you should do** I don't understand **why you should do it** in term of mathematical explanation.
I mean, let's take a concrete example: I have a variable `Gender` with values `Male` or `Female`. If I take the multilinear model equation I get:

$$y = B_0 + x_1B_1 + x_2B_2$$

with $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = 0$. So I get: $y=0+1\times1 + 0\times1$ so how is it different from $y=0+1\times1$ (which the second dummy variable removed ?
Could someone give me a **concrete** mathematical example of how this "trap" works?
Thanks

Comment: You seem to describe a model for just a single observation!  With $n$ observations, $B_0$ is a vector of ones, $B_1$ is a binary vector, $B_2$ is a binary vector, and (by construction) $B_0 = B_1+B_2$: that's collinearity.  Regardless, your question itself contains the concrete example you ask for.

Comment: Oh ok I see, that makes sense. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

We can see from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity#:%7E:text=Multicollinearity%20refers%20to%20a%20situation,equal%20to%201%20or%20%E2%88%921.) that:

> Multicollinearity refers to a situation in which two or more explanatory variables in a multiple regression model are highly linearly related.

In your case, that means that
$$x_1 = 1-x_2$$ and hence, your equation becomes
\begin{align}
y &= B_0 + x_1B_1 + x_2B_2 \\
  &= B_0 + B_1(1-x_2) + B_2 x_2 \\
  &= (B_0+B_1) + (B_2-B_1)x_2 
\end{align}

It is obvious that $(B_0+B_1) + (B_2-B_1)x_2$ is equivalently $\alpha + \beta x$ which entails only one variable.

Reference: [Dummy Variable Trap](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/dummy-variable-trap-c6d4a387f10a)