# R: Why does type III ANOVA require contrasts that sum to zero?

Tags: r, regression, anova, contrasts

The explanation offered [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/anova-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/amp/) is "over parameterization" of the multi-way ANOVA model, but I don't understand this statement.

In my own fiddling with 2-way, binary factor ANOVA, I can see that the full models produce the same predictions while the reduced (`drop1`) models do not. The key seems to be the coding of the variable interaction (`and` vs. `xor` for treatment vs. sum). When I compare the full model (`~ A*B`) with a model including only `B` and `xor(A,B)`, I get the "correct" difference in the sums of squared residuals for `A`, regardless of the type of contrasts used.

Why is one representation more valid for unbalanced data? What is the ***statistical reasoning*** behind this preference (`^`/`*` over `&`) and how does this relate to the issue of "over-parameterization"?

Comment: As this question is over a year old, I wonder whether you have found an answer meanwhile that you would like to share. I have only found the assertion that zero-sum contrasts are required, but nowhere an explanation. I only found a remark by Venables from 2000 that the fact that the result of a type III ANOVA depends on the factor coding is a sign that performing type III ANOVA is "something silly".

Comment: Never found an answer but I also stopped looking. My own experiments suggested to me that type III is equivalent to a LRT. I suppose type III is "silly" from a hypothesis testing standpoint since you are accounting for an interaction in the standalone effect of that same predictor, but such an approach is reasonable from a model selection standpoint. A linear model already assumes that (co)-linearity is a reasonably expressive model for the data generating process, while model selection alone does not require this assumption--a bilinear model could still "win out".

Comment: Venables actually referred to the factor coding issue as an indicator of "sillyness". The same contrasts issue allegedly applies to the R function *drop1*, which does "type II" ANOVA, i.e. removes only "reasonable" terms. Recently, I have stumbled acccross teh *relaimpo* package, which implements a method of averaging over "type I" ANOVA's in all possible permutations, thereby making the result no longer order depndent and providing a more reasonable index for variable importance.

Comment: That's interesting. Haven't needed to do an ANOVA in some time though.

Comment: I wonder how they keep their algorithm from being super-exponential in the number of predictors.

Comment: "how they keep their algorithm from being super-exponential in the number of predictors" They don't. The method (aka "dominance analysis") is therefore only feasible after variable selection or when there are few predictors from the start.

Answer (score 0):

The clearest explanation of this that I've found is from Bill Venables, in his recent vignette, "Coding Matrices, Contrast Matrices and Linear Models".

Basically it's so that the underlying hypothesis behind testing for a main effect, corresponds with what people might intuitively expect a main effect to be. As far as I can tell there is no problem at all if you understand exactly what you're testing for in terms of a contrast of cell means. One can choose various model intercepts using relevel() and contr.treatment: it should be expected that p-values for main effects terms will change with the changing intercepts.

Answer (score 0):

The full model is overdetermined and needs to drop one of the factors (which get turned into n-1 dummy variables instead of n dummy variables, see: [The dummy variable trap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340368/)). Which factor is dropped is arbitrary and this makes the location of the intercept arbitrary. See

- [Order of variables in R's lm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/501241/)
- [Both variables of my GLMM output are significant. Don't know how to interpret it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308556/)

The use of sum contrasts instead of treatment contrasts places the intercept in the middle, instead at one of the factors.

It changes a model like:

$$y_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_i + \beta_3 z_i + \beta_4 x_1z_i + \epsilon_i$$

which is effectively

$$y_i = \begin{cases}
\beta_1 & \quad \text{if $x_i = 0$ and $z_i = 0$}\\
\beta_1+\beta_2 & \quad \text{if $x_i = 1$ and $z_i = 0$}\\
\beta_1+\beta_3 & \quad \text{if $x_i = 0$ and $z_i = 1$}\\
\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3+\beta_4 & \quad \text{if $x_i = 1$ and $z_i = 1$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

into

$$y_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2 (2x_i-1) + \beta_3 (2z_i-1) + \beta_4 (2x_i-1)(2z_i-1) + \epsilon_i$$

which is effectively

$$y_i = \begin{cases}
\beta_1-\beta_2-\beta_3+\beta_4& \quad \text{if $x_i = 0$ and $z_i = 0$}\\
\beta_1+\beta_2-\beta_3-\beta_4 & \quad \text{if $x_i = 1$ and $z_i = 0$}\\
\beta_1-\beta_2+\beta_3-\beta_4 & \quad \text{if $x_i = 0$ and $z_i = 1$}\\
\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3+\beta_4 & \quad \text{if $x_i = 1$ and $z_i = 1$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

The estimates for the full model will be the same, there is no difference there (only slightly different coëfficiënts, but effectively the same estimates).

The effect/difference is that the model after dropping a main effect will be falling back to a different model, because the intercept is placed differently.

Whether or not the use of these type of contrasts make sense is not a strict rule. The use of type III contrasts with an interaction term are not very easy to interpret (and often it makes no sense with whatever contrasts you do it). It may depend on the case where one whishes to place the intercept.